# ijcadには、transientmanagerは実装されていないのでしょうか。

Tags: .net, ijcad

AUTOCADのAutodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterfaceに存在するtransientmanagerは、IJCADには実装されていないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

IJCADの.NET APIでは、TransientManagerが存在しないというエラーが発生していますので、TransientManagerクラスは実装されていないという事だと思います。